# Do i need to build my web app using .net framework 4.5 and above if <performanceScenario value="HighDensityWebHosting" /> need to be used?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, garbage-collection

from documentation it mentioned  required a .net framework 4.5. Does that mean i just need to install .net framework 4.5 in my hosting server ? Or i also need to rebuild my web application with .net 4.5 or above?

My existing web application have a mixture of 4.0 and 4.5. Should all upgrade to the same .net framework version?

https://web.archive.org/web/20160621111228/http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc_perf_5

> Tuning garbage collection to optimize for memory
> Requirement: .NET Framework 4.5

> Once a site is running, its use of the garbage-collector (GC) heap can be a significant factor in its memory consumption. Like any garbage collector, the .NET Framework GC makes tradeoffs between CPU time (frequency and significance of collections) and memory consumption (extra space that is used for new, freed, or free-able objects). For previous releases, we have provided guidance on how to configure the GC to achieve the right balance (for example, see ASP.NET 2.0/3.5 Shared Hosting Configuration).

> For the .NET Framework 4.5, instead of multiple standalone settings, a workload-defined configuration setting is available that enables all of the previously recommended GC settings as well as new tuning that delivers additional performance for the per-site working set.

> To enable GC memory tuning, add the following setting to the Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config file:

```
<performanceScenario value="HighDensityWebHosting"  />
```

(If you're familiar with the previous guidance for changes to aspnet.config, note that this setting replaces the old settings — for example, there is no need to set gcServer, gcConcurrent, etc. You do not have to remove the old settings.)

Comment: It it not 100% clear if you do have to re-compile your site as 4.5. however, why risk the issue, and thus I would re-build and re-compile and re-deploy the site with the framework set to 4.5 if I was going to use .net 4.5 features. It's not really worth the time and effort and risk as compared to a simple re-compile and then re-publish the site built as 4.5 anyway. It takes LESS TIME then you having written the above post. This being the case, then I would simple re-deploy the site as built to 4.5. In fact, if the site builds as 4.5, then if 4.8.1 is on the server, then build to that.

Comment: Furthermore, 4.8.1 is esseanctialy all the bug fixes and all the SP updates and all of the patches and fixed deployed as 4.8.1. In other words, the compelling reason to bump the project settings to 4.8.1 is that you now don't need to worry if the .net libraries (4.0 or whatever) has been updated, since with 4.8.1, all of the patches and bug fixes - including memory leaks are included in 4.8.1. So, in place of hoping that some updates and patches  to .net are or have been installed? Well,  by going with 4.8.1, you can be sure all those .net fixes and updates are installed.

Comment: Hi @AlbertD.Kallal, thanks for the comment. Is there any particular reason why this specific version 4.8.1? As of current, the web app is a mixture of 4.0 and 4.5 and we wanted to align them into one .net version instead. Recompile can be done easily but we have to plan for it as the web app is huge and required a lot of test which is done manually at this stage hence we have to plan this carefully. Any comment is welcome =)

Comment: 4.5 would be fine. I only suggested 4.8.1, since in theory, any issues or bug(s) that existed in 4.5 that were and have been fixed? They would be included in 4.8.1.  In other words, I am suggesting that 4.8.1 would be somewhat better, but probably not better enough warrent you moving everything to 4.8.1. However, I would build to 4.5. The older parts in 4.0 will thus/then be running as 4.5 and thus you fine anyway. In other  words, the parts that are currently 4.0 are fine as is (no need to re-build), and if the main project (web site) build is 4.5, then you are all fine anyway